# Can't make Files and Folders

Tags: java, file, mkdir

So i'm working on a simple Windows Explorer replacement. I want to add the ability to create Folders and Files. For some reason, it only works when i'm in my root or c:/ folder, but as soon as it's somewhere else (for example C:\Program Files (x86)) it doesn't work. I either get a java.io.IOException: Access Denied when i create a File and when i try to create a folder, no Exception comes up, but no folder is created.

This is my code for a new file:

```
String location = getPath();
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fill in the name of the new file. \nDon't forget to add file type (.txt, .pdf).", null);
if(name == null){

}
else {
    File newFile = new File(location + "\\" + name);
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        flag = newFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException Io) {
        JFrame messageDialog = new JFrame("Error!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(messageDialog, "File creation failed with the following reason: \n" + Io);
        }
    }
```

This is my code for a new Folder:

```
String location = getPath();
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fill in the name of the new folder.", null);
if(name == null){

}
else {
    File newFolder = new File(location + "\\" + name);
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        flag = newFolder.mkdir();
    } catch (SecurityException Se) {
        JFrame messageDialog = new JFrame("Error!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(messageDialog, "Folder creation failed with the following reason: \n" + Se);
        }
    }
```

I'm stuck right now and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong to get rid of the access denied error.

Short explenation of how this program works:
My program shows a list of all folders and files from a selected File. 
That File is a field in the class JXploreFile called "currentFile", which behaves almost the same as a File. 
When browsing through the folders, the currentFile is set to a new JXploreFile, containing the new folder you are in as File. 
When creating a new folder/file, my program ask the path the user is currently browsing in with the method getPath().

Thanks for the help!

Image of my program:
[image: Image of my program]

Comment: Are you getting this error in every folder or in Windows system folders only?

Comment: You most likely don't have permission to write to C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: [This has nothing to do with your code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx).

Comment: I can only add files and folder to c:/ (so not further in c:/) and to my desktop

Comment: "Access Denied": what do you not understand about that?

Comment: I do understand that i have no acces to write there, but my main questions are: How do i solve this? Why is this error not showing when creating folder?

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to make any I/O operation just check if you have the permission

go to the parent directory (your case `location`)

then do something like

```
File f = new File(location);

    if(f.canWrite()) {
            /*your full folder creation code here */
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: I tried this, just to see if i've got any permissions. I actually dont have permission when i try to create a new file or folder.

So i tried writing to My Documents instead, but the file was not able to write (!f.canWrite()). I looked up the path() and absolutePath() for my documents, which was:

Documenten

C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Programmeren 2\nl.hz.ict.lobb0009.jxplorer\::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\Documents.library-ms

Any idea why it shows up like that?

Also, i added an image of my program to my original post

Comment: for writing in Documents  the parent path will look like `C:\Users\UserName\Documents`. So here `location="C:\Users\UserName\Documents"`. Then do other operations.

Comment: I think i haven't been clear enough.
My program shows a list of all folders and files from a selected File (is called currentFile which is an JXploreFile, containing a File). When browsing through the folders, the currentFile is set to a new JXploreFile, containing the new folder as File. When creating a new folder/file, my program ask the path the user is currently browsing in with the method getPath(). But that method returns  "C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Programmeren 2\nl.hz.ict.lobb0009.jxplorer\::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\Documents‌​.library-ms" when you are in documents

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
String location ="c:\\user\<<youruser>>\\my documents"
```

or a folder with full perission to write